# How can switched capacitor converter be useful when its output is not regulated?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, charge-pump, switched-capacitor

The charge-pump converter also known as switched capacitor converter and flying capacitor converter is a type of inductorless switching voltage source i.e SMPS. It can generate a voltage higher than the input with less noise than a boost converter.

The primary issue with this circuit is that the output voltage drops as the load increases. This means that as more current is drawn, the output voltage starts to drop. This basically means that the output voltage is unregulated.

Now my question is, why is such a power supply useful and where does it find applications? I thought that an unregulated power supply is not actually useful. Am I wrong?

Comment: It regulates by virtue that the input supply is regulated. OK it's not great under heavy loads but, there are literally thousands of applications that are low-power and require a low-power negative supply because they run from a single battery.

Comment: Could you give some specific example? Just a few mA will cause the output voltage to drop. I do understand why/how this would be a great voltage source.

Comment: Not really because you are asking for opinions and you probably recall that these types of question are off-topic.

Comment: RS232 drivers come to mind, generating the -5V rail off of single supply.

Comment: Generating a supply for an op-amp, either a negative rail or a positive rail greater than the available input voltage would be a possible application.  The op-amp's PSRR would help reject changes in the supply voltage.

Comment: The ones I have seen are used where the load current doesn’t vary much and are low current.

Comment: If we use it with op-amp, we assume that the output is never supposed to saturate, correct? Because if it does, then it will hit the rail voltage which is not regulated. Also, if we use it with RS232 driver, we assume that it can work with a range on input voltage and still generate output pulses at a specific voltage e.g 12V. Thus, in both cases, we have a scenario where there is a single IC that can work across a range on input voltage without detrimental impact on their actual purpose/function in the circuit?

Comment: Many motor controllers have charge pumps to supply a gate voltage higher than the supply.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead The same is true of switching regulators in general; any that have a high-side switch will use a charge pump (called a bootstrap circuit in this application) to drive its gate.

Comment: See Cockcroft–Walton generator, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator, as an example; one way to get high-energy x-rays.

Comment: @Andyaka "Where is it useful" doesn't strike me as opinion-based.

Comment: Unregulated (or "poorly" regulated) power supplies are in use all over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your last question first: yes, you are wrong in your thinking that an unregulated power supply is not actually useful. 
To keep my answer shorter and more to the point, I will focus on the switched capacitor converter.

First of all, switched capacitor converter is typically used for circuits which don't require much supply current, usually in signal-processing or control circuits like differential line drivers or any signal/control outputs which require voltages higher than, or of opposite polarity to, the available supply voltage. MOSFET/IGBT drivers are one of such areas of use as well.

Secondly, their output is not really unregulated per se, because it is usually a reflection of the regulated voltage from which it is derived - a switched capacitor voltage doubler will have exactly twice the supply voltage, while a negative voltage derived in similar fashion is an oppositely polarized replica of the supply voltage. The output voltage will not exceed the value of the supply voltage either as doubled or as reversed. 
Switched capacitor converters are thus kept regulated by the stable supply voltage and low currents at their outputs.

Regarding regulation, MOST of the power supplies in the past have been unregulated and have been quite useful without noticeable "side-effects": audio amplifiers have typically used unregulated voltages, your microwave oven uses an unregulated supply voltage... 
Although they were "unregulated", their voltage variation was usually narrow as it typically reflected the power line voltage which itself was/is regulated within a few percent.

Many circuits/devices don't need precise or very stable voltages. Even many MCUs can work over a range of voltages, like 2.7-3.6V or even 2.5-5.5V, for example. A specific, precise, regulated voltage is typically used for (common) references in a circuit.

Comment: I see. So some devices need the voltage to be stable within a very narrow range. However, others are able to work fine even if thats not the case. The emphasis on having a stable regulated power supply everywhere (at 3.3V, 1.8V, 1.2V, 5V e.t.c) I have seen so far in my experience led me to believe that an unregulated power supply is actually a defect.

Comment: Now to just the last point, when we say small current? What constites as small? A few mA, some 10s of mA? a few hundred mA?

Comment: @quantum231 The "small current" could be from few uA to tens of mA typically, but it can be higher. It is a relative term; it is small compared to the amount the switched capacitor circuit can provide.

Comment: Note that there are combination regulating charge pumps.  These may be regulated by gating the clock, or frequency modulation, or a proper LDO at the output. The above remains true of course for the charge pump section within.

Comment: @TimWilliams You're right. I didn't mention those as the focus was on unregulated ones.